# In Odoo 17, how do I override the default accounts set in the journal entry created by a customer payment?

Tags: methods, odoo, overriding

When creating a customer payment, the journal entry is comprised of a debit to the bank account that is set on account.journal and a credit to the receivable account that is set on res.partner.

I want to override those defaults if a custom boolean field (trust_account_deposit) I have created on account.payment is set to true.

I have also created booleans for account.account to mark an account as 'trust_bank_account' and another account as 'trust_receivable_account', and I want the customer payment to generate a journal entry that uses those accounts for the debit and credit items.

Above is the code I have so far but I don't know how to override the required method.  How can I achieve the setting of custom accounts in the journal entry?

Below is the code I have so far but I don't know how to override the required method.  How can I achieve the setting of custom accounts in the journal entry?

````
class AccountAccount(models.Model):    
    ​_inherit = 'account.account'
    
    ​trust_bank_account = fields.Boolean("Trust Bank Account", default=False)    
    ​trust_receivable_account = fields.Boolean("Trust Receivable Account", default=False)
    
    ​@api.constrains('trust_bank_account','trust_receivable_account')   
        def _check_unique_trust_accounts(self):        
    ​    ​for record in self:            
    ​   ​if record.trust_bank_account and record.trust_receivable_account:
    ​   ​    raise ValidationError("An account cannot be both Trust Bank Account and Trust Receivable Account.")

                if record.trust_bank_account:
    ​   ​    existing_trust_bank_account = self.env['account.account'].search([
                        ('trust_bank_account', '=', True),
                        ('id', '!=', record.id),
                ])
                if existing_trust_account_journal:
                    raise ValidationError("There can be only one Trust Account Journal.")

class AccountPayment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment'

    trust_account_deposit = fields.Boolean("Trust Account Deposit", default=False)
    trust_account_transfer = fields.Boolean("Trust Account Transfer", default=False)

    @api.constrains('trust_account_deposit', 'trust_account_transfer')
    def _check_unique_trust_payment_type(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.trust_account_deposit and record.trust_account_transfer:
                raise ValidationError("A payment record cannot be both Trust Account Deposit and Trust Account Transfer.")```
````